# Overline in ggplot axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtext

I'm trying to create some ggplot with overlined axis title. Using a reproducible example, my code is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

data("iris")

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("<span style = 'text-decoration: overline;'>Sepal</span> <span style = 'color: #00e000;'>Length</span>") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_markdown())
```

The result, however, doesn't work as expected (overline missing on "Sepal"):

[image: image1]

Comment: From the [Github readme](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext):

"It currently can make text bold or italics, can change the font, color, or size of a piece of text, can place text as sub- or superscript, and has extremely rudimentary image support. No other features are currently supported."

Overlines a probably not supported.

Comment: `ggtext` works via the `gridtext` package, which implements some elements of markdown and css by translating them into `grid` graphics. `gridtext` does its own parsing and translation to grid, using a small but very commonly used subset of tags and css attributes, rather than providing a full markdown and css implementation. It does not handle overlines, as @teunbrand points out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind losing the color, you can do it using `plotmath` methods:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab(expression(paste(over(,"Sepal"), atop(," Length"))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, `ggtext` does not handle overlines. Perhaps the simplest way to get the same effect without having to turn clipping off and draw line segments is to use two-line text with underscores on the top line:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

data("iris")

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab(paste0("____<span style = 'color: #ffffff'>.Length</span><br>",
       "<span>Sepal.<span style = 'color: #00e000;'>Length</span>")) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_markdown())
```

[image]